# Lagrangian function and first order necessary optimality conditions

Tags: convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, operations-research

I am given the following equality constrained convex QP.

$$\min_x \frac{1}{2}x'Hx+g'x$$
$$st. A'x+b=0$$

with $H\succ 0$.

I want to find the Lagrangian function for this problem and the first order necessary optimality conditions.

**Attempt**
I found the lagrangian to be:
$$L(x,\lambda)=\frac{1}{2}x'Hx+g'x-\lambda(A'x+b)$$

The first order necessary optimality condition I found to be:
$$\nabla_x(\frac{1}{2}x'Hx+g'x)-\lambda\nabla(A'x+b)$$

I this correct, or am I at least on the right track?
I am especially unsure about the first order necessary optimality condition....

I hope some of you can help me! The help would be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: Looks good to me. To be more precise, the first order condition is $\nabla_x (\frac{1}{2}x' H x + g'x) - \lambda \nabla (A' x + b) = 0$. You just need to explicitly calculate this gradient, which should give you $Hx + g - \lambda A$. Let me know if you have follow-up questions.

Comment: Actually, I need you to clarify a few definitions, since different literature has different conventions. Usually, the $L(x, \lambda) = \frac{1}{2}x'H x + g'x - \lambda(A'x + b)$ you wrote is called the augmented Lagrangian. $h(\lambda) = \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} L(x, \lambda)$ is called the Lagrangian dual function. I have seen them both referred to as the "Lagrangian function" in various sources. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: I think it is the augemented Lagrangian that I'm looking for. The exercise only said "what is the Lagrangian function for the QP". :)

Comment: Ok. Then I think you are pretty much done. (One small detail I wish to point out: Judging from how it's written, $A'x + b$ seems to be a vector in, say, $\mathbf{R}^m$, correct? If that's the case, the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ should also be a vector in $\mathbf{R}^m$. So instead of $\lambda (A'x + b)$ appearing in $L(x, \lambda)$, it should be $\lambda' (A'x + b)$. The first order condition is $\nabla_x (\frac{1}{2}x'H x + g'x) - \lambda' \nabla (A'x + b) = 0$, which simplifies to $Hx + g - A\lambda = 0$.)